# Send value to servlet with javascript

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript function I do like this in order to redirect parameters to servlet:

```
var ids1=document.getElementById("projet").value;
document.location.href("http://localhost:8080/Opc_Web_App/ServletAffectation?ids1="+ids1);
```

and in the servlet I do the following to get Value:

```
String idprojet= request.getParameter("ids1");
System.out.println("le projet selectionné est :" +idprojet);
```

the problem that i didn't have the result of System.out.print in my screen; so in other terms the servlet didn't get the parameter.

I can not see the problem until now.
Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that

```
var ids1=document.getElementById("projet").value;
```

is returning nothing?

Also,

```
System.out.println(..)
```

prints into the console, or the terminal prompt, not the browser's page.. To output into the browser, use

```
 response.getWriter().println(..)
```